# How to pick the first entry out of all the list

Tags: sql, oracle

In this test table, with below data. Even though how many entries are there, need to pick the first valid record for that day.
Also, there is chance that for that day where rank no might increase.

| A | B | STATUS | LOAD_DATE | RANKNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SAMPLE | SAMPLE | VALID | 10-Jan-22 | 3 |
| SAMPLE | SAMPLE | INVALID | 10-Jan-22 | 5 |
| SAMPLE | SAMPLE | VALID | 10-Jan-22 | 6 ** |
| SAMPLE | SAMPLE | VALID | 1-Jan-22 | 10 |
| SAMPLE | SAMPLE | INVALID | 1-Jan-22 | 12 |
| SAMPLE | SAMPLE | INVALID | 1-Jan-22 | 12 |  |

For Jan 10, 2022 the expected output is, line:

| A | B | STATUS | LOAD_DATE | RANKNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SAMPLE | SAMPLE | VALID | 10-Jan-22 | 6 ** |

We can do `select * from test where rankno = 6` (this is for 10-jan-22) but there might be chance that for 11-jan-22 there will be only 2 records, we need to pick record with highest `rankno`

**if I query with Load_date, it should fetch valid record with highest rankno.**

```
SELECT A, B, Status, load_date 
FROM   test
WHERE  status = 'VALID' 
AND    ....
```

or can we?

```
SELECT max(rankno) 
FROM   test 
WHERE  load_date = '10-JAN-22'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we use RANK() in a sub query to get the wanted row in the outer query.

> ```
> create table test (
> A varchar(10),
> B varchar(10),
> STATUS VARCHAR (10),
> LOAD_DATE date,
> RANKNO int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test (A,B,STATUS,LOAD_DATE,RANKNO)
> SELECT 'SAMPLE','SAMPLE','VALID',TO_DATE('2022-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 'SAMPLE','SAMPLE','INVALID',TO_DATE('2022-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 'SAMPLE','SAMPLE','VALID',TO_DATE('2022-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ,6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 'SAMPLE','SAMPLE','VALID',TO_DATE('2022-01-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 'SAMPLE','SAMPLE','INVALID',TO_DATE('2022-01-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
> SELECT 'SAMPLE','SAMPLE','INVALID',TO_DATE('2022-01-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),14 FROM DUAL
> ```

6 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM 
> (SELECT 
>   A, B, Status, 
>   load_date ,
>   ROWNUM,
>   RANKNO,
>   RANK() OVER (
>      ORDER BY load_date ASC,
>        RANKNO DESC) rnk
> FROM test 
> WHERE 
>   status = 'VALID' 
>   --AND ROWNUM = 1
> ORDER BY 
>   load_date ASC,
>   RANKNO DESC)s
> WHERE rnk = 1;
> ```

> ```
> A      | B      | STATUS | LOAD_DATE | ROWNUM | RANKNO | RNK
> :----- | :----- | :----- | :-------- | -----: | -----: | --:
> SAMPLE | SAMPLE | VALID  | 01-JAN-22 |      2 |      6 |   1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=44fbb6b02f1c155a5520bbe9c7aa361b)*

Comment: Do not use `RANK` as it can return multiple rows when there are ties for first. Use `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will return the row in blue.
`FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` returns only the first row according to the ORDER BY specified.

```
SELECT 
  A, B, Status, 
  load_date,
  RANKNO,
  ROWNUM
FROM test 
WHERE status = 'VALID' 
ORDER BY 
  load_date ASC,
  RANKNO DESC
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=793f06cc4a3d7ea6e978eb683ce3d095

Comment: it says command is not properly ended at limit 1

Comment: Added `;` please try again

Comment: Yes, have done. Still same error.
So this will work without using max or something? @kendle

Comment: Sorry I forgot in oracle we have to use `ROWNUM = 1` and not LIMIT

Comment: It is picking Low rankno. Rankno 3 is getting picked, eventhough we sort by descending order.

Comment: You need to order first, than in an outer `SELECT` limit with `ROWNUM`.

Comment: Yes, even after that, low rankno is getting picked.

Comment: @Karuna - Are you trying to retrieve a single row for a *single* date - or multiple dates?

Comment: Got it `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` I was sure there was a way. Oracle couldn't be lacking such a basic function as LIMIT, even if they have there own syntax!

Comment: @SOS: For single date